# Instantiate Map<Id, SObject> with final keyword

Tags: apex, map

I understand I can declare a variable with the `final` keyword as below...

```
private final List<User> userList = [SELECT Id FROM User];
```

... That will generate an array that, when supplied with a value, can't be changed. I'd like to do the same thing, only using a Map.

I've tried:

```
private final Map<Id, User> userList = [SELECT Id FROM User];
```

But I can an error arround trying to supply a `List<>` type to a `Map<>`, which I understand. Additionally I've tried:

```
private final Map<Id, User> mapUserIdToUser {
  get {
    if (mapUserIdToUser == null) {
      mapUserIdToUser = new Map<Id, User>();
      for (User user : [SELECT Id FROM User]) {
        mapUserIdToUser.put(user.Id, user);
      }
    }

    return mapUserIdToUser;
  }
}
```

But then I get the following error:

> Methods are final by default, Use virtual to declare methods that can be overriden

Ideally I'd like to do something as short and sweet as the first line of code I supplied at the top, so really I'm looking at the cleanest way possible to declare a `Map<Id, SObject>` using the `final` keyword as once this variable has been supplied with values, it won't change.

**Edit**

I may be misunderstanding something pretty simple, but given the error I know I *could* just remove `final` and write something like below:

```
private final Map<Id, User> mapUserIdToUser {
  get {
    if (mapUserIdToUser == null) {
    [...]
```

But would this act as final and disallow any changes to the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
private final Map<Id, User> userList = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id FROM User]);
```

Comment: Perfect, I figured it'd be something simple. I think I was overthinking it!